# Unable to disable find my iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have disable find my iPhone from icloud on to the internet and from my phone as well, but it still showing on from apple website, tried turn on and off again tried so many things but its is still sowing that its on, and I am unable to reset the phone on to factory settings, when I try to reset the phone after apple bar it  goes to the spining wheel and it spines for ever but does not reset the phone on to factory settings

Answer (score 1):

i've been stuck in this situation -- something went wonky with it.  my solution was to use findmyiphone to remotely wipe the phone.  it will wipe it and then ask you for the appleid and password.  then it finally worked and it was free of all accounts.